# Laravel 5.4 - Basic Tests - NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, routes, phpunit

I have a problem running the basic test that ships with Laravel:

`app/tests/Feature/ExampleTest.php`

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

When I run it I get the exception `NotFoundHttpException`. I can access my website in the browser without problems. This problem appears to apply to all my routes.

Using Laravel 5.4

The route `/` is defined in `app/routes/web.php`.

Comment: Can you post the routes.php code?

Comment: _app/routes/web.php_:

`<?php

Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); });
`

Comment: So you want to access to testBasicTest() function but not return to view, right?

Comment: I have just discovered something very interesting. My machine hosts multiple web pages. In my Laravel .env file I have: `APP_URL=https://myserver/product-service` , changing this to `APP_URL=https://myserver` prevents the NotFoundHttpException. This is not a solution, however

Comment: Seems related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967227/laravel-phpunit-not-getting-right-url

Answer (score 2):

It seems that in Laravel 5.4 `$baseUrl` property was removed from `TestCase` class.

You may add some `setUp` to your `ExampleTest`:

```
function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    config(['app.url' => 'https://myserver']);
}
```

Hope this helps!